# Unable to make RPi image through win32diskimager any solution?

Tags: sd-card, pi-3b+

The SD card with RPi OS is corrupted while trying to make a flashed card and I tried to create its image through Win32 disk imager. I keep getting I/O error while reading.

Comment: Welcome -- but you need to explain more precisely exactly what you did to create the card and exactly what happened.  Right now your question is too vague to answer except with "Follow the official directions": https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md If that's what you did, say that's what you did and list the steps you took *even if that seems redundant to you*.

Comment: if the SD card contains important data, then give it to someone who has the skill to retrieve the data ... your question indicates that you should not attempt the retrieval

Comment: Question edited . You should use balena ether instead.